# Clojure, counting the words in a map

Tags: clojure

I'm relatively new to Clojure so what i might be asking could be completely wrong. Basically I want to create a function called wordCount which counts the words that are passed in from another method. The structure of my code is below;

```
( defn  createWordMap [x]   
  (cond
   (= (mod x 3) 0) "divisible by 3"
 :else (print-str x))
)

( defn  wordCount [x]   
  ;; I want to count the words in the map created and passed in
)

( wordCount ( map createWordMap ( range 100 ) ) )
```

Comment: In your example, you pass in a sequence that looks like `("divisible by 3" "1" "2" "divisible by 3" "4" "5" "divisible by 3" "7" "8" "divisible by 3" ...)`. Should the output be the sum of all of the words? (For example, 3 for the first plus 1 for the second, and so on ...)

Comment: You see, it's more of a question I have to answer. But I don't want the answer to be given to me, I want to learn what everything is doing. I've had a look at multiple resources online trying to learn. As regards to your question, it should return a list, which I think it is doing ... when I just call createWordMap it returns the relevant things but with that I want to count the words and have the ability to get the words. For example be like; x.get(0) which would return the first element. Thanks for your reply

Comment: In the comment inside the definition of `wordCount` it refers to `x` as being a map, but the last line of your example code causes a sequence to be passed in as `x`. Perhaps a sample value for `x`, along with the value that `wordCount` would return would clarify.

Comment: Is there anyway to iterate over a sequence and displaying values within wordCount ?

Comment: If you put `(prn x)` inside of `wordCount`, it will display the contents of `x`.

Comment: Ah, I see. So x is just a big string sort of speak.

Comment: In your example, `x` is a sequence of strings.

Comment: Thanks for your help Mike, you've helped me understand how all this works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've divided this into sections. I suggest you stop reading at the end of each section and see how much further you can get.

---

Your `createWordMap` function looks wrong.

- If the condition is true, it *returns* a string.
- If the condition is false, it *prints* a string and returns `nil`.

And there is no need to use `cond` here. `if` will do as well.

---

Your function that takes a number to a string could be

```
(defn words [x]
  (if (= (mod x 3) 0)
    "divisible by 3"
    (str x)))
```

It doesn't create a map, so let's just call it `words`.

---

Now we need something to count the words in a string. As [the other solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27637473/1562315) did, we count the spaces and add 1. Its faster and more general to do this with regular expressions, but we'll leave that aside for now.

---

```
(defn count-words [s]
  (->> s
     (filter #{\space})
     count
     inc))
```

- The `->>` macro threads successive function calls.
- The set `#{\space}` operates as a function that returns true only on
  a space.

---

Now we need to

- map the numbers from `0` to `99` to their strings,
- count the words in each,
- and add them together.

If you don't want to see the answer, then read no further.

---

```
(apply + (map (comp count-words words) (range 100)))
;168
```

**Using Regular Expressions**

If we want to get at the words - not just count them, we can use [`re-seq`](http://conj.io/store/org.clojure/clojure/1.7.0-alpha4/clojure.core/re-seq/):

```
(re-seq #"\w+" "mary had a little lamb")
;("mary" "had" "a" "little" "lamb")
```

This accepts any sequence of white-space characters as a word separator.

Then the answer could be expressed

```
(apply + (map (comp count #(re-seq #"\w+" %) words) (range 100)))
```

Comment: This is great, thank you. I have a question about count-words, it filters it basically splitting the string at every space. Is there anyway to store all of the split words in a way that allows me to iterate over each word?

Comment: @Jordan See appendix to answer above.

Answer (score 0):

naive solution would be

```
(defn wordCount [x] (reduce + (map #(inc (count (filter (partial = \space) %))) x)))
```

supposing x are trimmed by default

```
(reduce + some-list-of-numbers) ;; sums a list of number
```

and

```
#(int (count (filter (partial = \space) %)))
```

is a function that counts the number of spaces and adds 1.

That's all.